# CSS grid not constraining number of columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my grid to only put 3 buttons per row, so that when I add a 4th, it should automatically be placed in the next row.

This is my code:

```css
.div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background: #3c763d;
}

.button {
  background: #27ae60;
  float: left;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 8.33%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
  color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
<h3>Make your selection!</h3>

<div>
  <div class="button">Rock</div>
  <div class="button">Paper</div>
  <div class="button">Scissors</div>
  <div class="button">Clear</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Instead, I keep getting left with a row of 4 buttons, instead of a row of 3, followed by a new row of 1. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, but there are a few things you need to fix to get this to work.

**1. Your grid CSS rules are in a class div that you don't use**: 
Your CSS rules for the grid are in `.div {...}` Either you meant that to be a `<div>` element (which won't work FYI - it would make *every* div a grid container!)  or forgot to add the div class to the grid element in your HTML.

Instead, add a class to your outer div e.g. `<div class="mygrid">` and add the grid css rules to that class, e.g.

```
.mygrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background: #3c763d;
    /* Extra info! You can use this for even grid gaps */
    grid-gap: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

**2. You are giving your buttons `width 8.33%`** - this will make your button 8.55% of the grid columns, which I assume you don't want :).

**3. You can also remove the `display:float`** from the buttons, as this will be managed automatically by the grid

**4. You can use `grid-gap` to create even gaps** between the grid elements instead of setting margins on them - this makes the gaps between the rows and cols the same because there i no margin-collapsing.
(You can use the same size padding on the container to pad the space evenly.)

**Working Example:**

```css
.mygrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background: #3c763d;
    grid-gap: 6px;
    padding: 6px;
}

.button {
    background: #27ae60;
    height: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
    color: #f9f9f9;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
<h3>Make your selection!</h3>

<div class="mygrid">
    <div class="button">Rock</div>
    <div class="button">Paper</div>
    <div class="button">Scissors</div>
    <div class="button">Clear</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, that was my initial issue- just forgot to add a class name to the div. Easy beginner mistake. This leaves me with other questions, but that got my initial issue to working, so thanks :)

Comment: @JimmyBlundell Glad to help! That was the main problem but I added some info to get over some other issues that might come up e.g. float, grid-gap etc. but the next big problem would have been tiny buttons because of the 8% width :)

Answer (score 2):

**#1 using grid Method**

`width:8.33%;float:left` not need for **button** also add a class to main div in grid i add as **maindiv** and styled for it instead style direct div affect all

```
.maindiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background: #3c763d;
}
```

```css
.maindiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background: #3c763d;
}

.button {
  background: #27ae60;
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  height: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
  color: #f9f9f9;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
<h3>Make your selection!</h3>

<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="button">Rock</div>
  <div class="button">Paper</div>
  <div class="button">Scissors</div>
  <div class="button">Clear</div>
</div>

</html>
```

**#2 Using flex method**

```css
.maindiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    background: #3c763d;
}

.button {
    background: #27ae60;
    margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    height: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
    color: #f9f9f9;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    max-width: calc(33.33% - 12px );
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 12px );
}
.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
<h3>Make your selection!</h3>

<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="button">Rock</div>
    <div class="button">Paper</div>
    <div class="button">Scissors</div>
    <div class="button">Clear</div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Good point about flex. This is the sort of thing it was designed for, after all.

Answer (score 0):

To this make sure to give the wrapping div a class.

So your HTML will be.

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <div class="button">Rock</div>
    <div class="button">Paper</div>
    <div class="button">Scissors</div>
    <div class="button">Clear</div>
</div>
```

Then your grid will have only 3 items as you want.

You may want to fix this width of each item by removing the `fixed width` you have so the buttons can fill up space in the gird.
remove it from class `.button` and you should be good to go.

```
.button{
      width: 8.33%;
}
```